# How can I convert an `enum` to a XAML vector icon object and display it multiple times within the same window?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a resource dictionary in a `Resources.xaml` file containing multiple vector icons (XAML format, `Canvas` in a `Viewbox`):

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Viewbox x:Key="Icon1" x:Shared="False">
        ...
    </Viewbox>
    <Viewbox x:Key="Icon2" x:Shared="False">
        ...
    </Viewbox>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

These icons can be displayed in a WPF window multiple times because I have used the `x:Shared="False` setting. For example, ...

```
<ContentControl Content="{StaticResource Icon1}" />
<ContentControl Content="{StaticResource Icon1}" />
```

... displays the `Icon1` icon twice as expected.

Now I'd like to convert an `enum` to the icon object so that an icon can be displayed based on an `enum` value (for nodes in a tree view). You would usually declare an `EnumToObjectConverter` in the `Resources.xaml`:

```
<local:EnumToObjectConverter x:Key="TreeIcons">
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Viewbox x:Key="Icon1" x:Shared="False">
            ...
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox x:Key="Icon2" x:Shared="False">
            ...
        </Viewbox>
    <ResourceDictionary>
</local:EnumToObjectConverter>
```

But since this is an embedded resource dictionary the `x:Shared` setting does not have any effect (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/x-shared-attribute) and referencing the image through the converter results in the icon being displayed only once in the Window or tree view, even when referenced in multiple places (the other places remain blank).

How can I do a mapping from an `enum` to the vector icon object so that icons are still properly displayed in multiple places?

Update: This example demonstrates the effect of the `x:Shared` setting (this is a NET Core 3.0 WPF application in case it makes any difference).

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="XamlIconTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamlIconTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>    
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="Icon1 (1st)" />
            <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource Icon1}" Margin="8"/>
            <Separator />
            <Label Content="Icon1 (2nd)" />
            <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource Icon1}" Margin="8"/>
            <Separator />
            <Label Content="Icon2 (1st)" />
            <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource Icon2}" Margin="8"/>
            <Separator />
            <Label Content="Icon2 (2nd)" />
            <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource Icon2}" Margin="8"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;

namespace XamlIconTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Resources.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamlIconTest">
    <!-- Icon1 without x:Shared -->
    <Path x:Key="Icon1" 
          Width="37.9858" Height="46.6386" Canvas.Left="19.186" Canvas.Top="14.2229" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 38.1789,60.8614L 19.186,37.7428L 38.1686,14.2229L 57.1718,37.7531L 38.1789,60.8614 Z "/>

    <!-- Icon2 with x:Shared -->
    <Path x:Key="Icon2" x:Shared="False" 
          Width="37.9858" Height="46.6386" Canvas.Left="19.186" Canvas.Top="14.2229" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 38.1789,60.8614L 19.186,37.7428L 38.1686,14.2229L 57.1718,37.7531L 38.1789,60.8614 Z "/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Displayed main window (note the missing Icon1 in the first row):

[image]

Comment: You should add an MVCE to your question.

Comment: Why are you declaring the resource as `Viewbox`? If these are normal XAML vector icons, your resource should just be the path data, which can be shared between multiple geometries. I don't see a need for `x:Shared` here.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks, I'll try that. The reason for `Viewbox` is mostly because the icon files came that way (`Path` in `Canvas` in `Viewbox`), so less editing. BTW, I have noticed that you have removed the WPF-Core tags; this is a NET Core project and I have included the tags in case that is relevant.

Comment: @Aybe If not resolved with PeterDuniho's suggestion then I will.

Comment: I don't see anything in your question specific to .NET Core or WPF on .NET Core. If you believe that those tags are needed, your question should explain what makes your question unique to that platform. Conversely, if you expect that WPF will work the same in this respect whether on desktop or Core, those tags aren't appropriate.

Comment: @PeterDuniho It shouldn't be different but WPF support in Net Core is very new. Anyhow, not need for the tags probably.

Comment: _"WPF support in Net Core is very new"_ -- yes, but should have 1-for-1 parity with desktop WPF, unlike the bastardized Silverlight and UWP XAML implementations. If you find a working solution on desktop that doesn't also work the same on Core, I would file a bug if I were you.

Comment: @PeterDuniho It does not work with `Path` either; I'll add an example shortly.

Comment: @Aybe I have added an example, thank you for your time.

Comment: @J.R. Consider making the path Data the resource, as Peter suggested. I don’t recall if you can do that with a string. I’ve done it with PathGeometry. Alternatively, a Style applied to Path could set Data as a string, plus Fill, etc. You shouldn’t have any trouble defining a style as a resource.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thanks, Ed, as you have seen in the updated example, `Path` itself did not work. The icon library I'm using has all icons defined in `Viewbox` enclosing `Canvas` enclosing one ore more `Path`. While `Path` demonstrates that `x:Shared` is required, moving away too much from the original icon definitions would complicate things.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, Sorry, you are right, I have misread the `Data` part. It seems a lot of effort to disassemble the icon library into the path data or even the paths (there can be multiple in one icon). The `Path` example reduces the problem down to the lowest portion of the icon that still demonstrates the need for `x:Shared`. -- Is there a no way to make `Path` or `Viewbox` icons work then?

Comment: As @Ed mentions, sharing the geometry data is the way to go and will work. That said, if you really want to use `Path` resources (or other visuals) as you've shown above with your converter, it will be up to your converter to clone the resource object as needed. I will note however that that approach violates the coding principle of DRY. One advantage (of several) to doing it the way I suggest is that you factor out the underlying data from the visual itself, and thus don't have to keep copy/pasting the visual for each different icon. This results in less code, and makes it easier to modify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question seems to boil down to two separate topics:

- The primary one, which is how to share vector graphics in a context where `x:Shared` has no effect (i.e. in a resource dictionary that's defined as a child of your converter).
- An implied secondary one, which is how to property select a specific vector graphic given an input value (e.g. an `enum` value).

First I will note: as a general rule it is my preference to use templates instead of `x:Shared=false` with explicit resources. It winds up doing basically the same thing — instantiating new visual objects for each value displayed — but IMHO is more idiomatic for WPF, which is designed entirely around the concept of templating and binding.

As far as addressing your issues goes…

Your MCVE does not involve code that uses a converter, but the basic principle would be the same, so I will provide an example based on the MCVE, not using a converter. The approach involves doing as I suggested in the comments, which is to declare a resource containing the path's data (i.e. the geometry), and then reuse that resource as needed. The data itself isn't a visual, and so can be shared arbitrarily.

First, the resource:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestSO58533019ShareVectorData"
                    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
  <PathGeometry x:Key="IconGeometry1">F1 M 38.1789,60.8614L 19.186,37.7428L 38.1686,14.2229L 57.1718,37.7531L 38.1789,60.8614 Z</PathGeometry>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then to use that, you can just define a `DataTemplate` that maps a `Geometry` object to the visual you want (in this case, a `Path` object):

```xml
<Window x:Class="TestSO58533019ShareVectorData.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestSO58533019ShareVectorData"
        xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
  <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary>
          <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Geometry}">
            <Path Width="37.9858" Height="46.6386" Canvas.Left="19.186" Canvas.Top="14.2229"
                  Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000"
                  Data="{Binding}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Window.Resources>
  <Grid>
    <StackPanel>
      <Label Content="IconGeometry1 (1st)" />
      <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource IconGeometry1}" Margin="8"/>
      <Separator />
      <Label Content="IconGeometry1 (2nd)" />
      <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource IconGeometry1}" Margin="8"/>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

This results in the display of the icon twice:

[image]

Now, the above approach could still be used with your converter technique. Your converter could return different `Geometry` objects depending on the `enum` value, which in turn could be bound to the `Data` property of a `Path` object as above. With some contortions, you could even have a `Path` resource item that does this, using `x:Shared=false` to reuse that resource item.

But IMHO that would be harder than necessary and not the right way to go. To me, conceptually what is going on is that you have an `enum` value, and you want to represent that very value with some graphic, depending on the value. That's exactly what WPF's templating features are for! They map one data type to another (i.e. your `enum` type to a `Path` object), and with styles you can conditionally configure the templated object as needed.

For the sake of simplicity I will use `int` rather than an actual `enum` value. But the basic idea is exactly the same. Note that a key benefit of doing it this way is to minimize the amount of code-behind. You *declare* for WPF what it is you want to happen, instead of having to write procedural code to do something yourself that WPF could instead do for you.

First, let's define a couple of different icons:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestSO58533019ShareVectorData"
                    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
  <PathGeometry x:Key="IconGeometry1">F1 M 38.1789,60.8614L 19.186,37.7428L 38.1686,14.2229L 57.1718,37.7531L 38.1789,60.8614 Z</PathGeometry>
  <PathGeometry x:Key="IconGeometry2">F1 M 38.1789,60.8614L 19.186,37.7428L 57.1718,37.7531L 38.1789,60.8614 Z</PathGeometry>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Now, let's define a template for `int`, where that template uses style triggers to use the appropriate geometry data, and the bound value is simply that `int` value:

```xml
<Window x:Class="TestSO58533019ShareVectorData.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:p="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestSO58533019ShareVectorData"
        xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
  <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary>
          <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type s:Int32}">
            <Path Width="37.9858" Height="46.6386" Canvas.Left="19.186" Canvas.Top="14.2229"
                  Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000">
              <Path.Style>
                <p:Style TargetType="Path">
                  <p:Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="1">
                      <DataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Data" Value="{StaticResource IconGeometry1}"/>
                      </DataTrigger.Setters>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="2">
                      <DataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Data" Value="{StaticResource IconGeometry2}"/>
                      </DataTrigger.Setters>
                    </DataTrigger>
                  </p:Style.Triggers>
                </p:Style>
              </Path.Style>
            </Path>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Window.Resources>
  <Grid>
    <StackPanel>
      <Label Content="1st int" />
      <ContentControl Margin="8">
        <ContentControl.Content>
          <s:Int32>1</s:Int32>
        </ContentControl.Content>
      </ContentControl>
      <Separator />
      <Label Content="2nd int" />
      <ContentControl Margin="8">
        <ContentControl.Content>
          <s:Int32>2</s:Int32>
        </ContentControl.Content>
      </ContentControl>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

With that code, you'll get this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, Peter. I was hoping to 'just use' my `Viewbox` icons but, alas, there does not seem to be an easier way. 
I know that I can re-load/clone from the resource stream in code but that doesn't feel right. As some people say, WPF makes difficult things easy and easy things hard to do, like displaying the same vector icon twice.